# Reconciling version in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

When I try to reconcile using ArcGIS for Desktop I got this message:

> the version could not be reconciled.the number of points is less than
>   required for feature.

What should I do?

---

I checked the details before and I didn't find less than 2 vertexes for line and less then 3 for polygon.

Comment: You've got an empty geometry. A line with one point or a polygon with less than 3. Find it by length = 0 and remove it prior to reconciling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I checked the details befor and I didn't find less than 2 vertexes for line and less then 3 for polygon.

Comment: This sounds like the layer properties are corrupt regarding the spatial index or the feature extent. Could you post more information on the version of the GDB, ArcGIS, RDBMS, etc? Does the error message specify which versioned object is causing the error? If so, I bet you can also reproduce this by attempting to zoom/pan to the affected area, as a drawing error will occur in 10.3 if you come across this issue. You may also drop your spatial index and attempt the reconcile without it, so you can troubleshoot without worrying about your edits being stuck.

Comment: Using the Repair Geometry or Check Geometry tool will fix/find conclusively if you have any geometry errors, that will need to be run for each feature class that is being reconciled... note that if you have points with an empty geometry you will also get that error.. this is because geodatabases are tolerant to bad geometries but SDE is not. Should you be unable to find any geometry errors delete the spatial index as @ORA-55378 indicated... this can also be rectified by exporting to XML and re-importing, however this could break your check-out... make sure you keep a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't an actual lack of minimum vertex count per entity type, but that there are likely coincident vertices causing improper construction.

I would suggest to examine the shape or geometry columns of your data for coincident vertices within the same geometry. You can put together a script to loop through and identify these if you have many feature classes and many geometries.

For example, this will reproduce your error if using Oracle SDO Geometry:

```
INSERT INTO sde.poly_sdo VALUES(
  1,SDO_GEOMETRY(2003,4326,NULL,SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1,1, 1,1)),NULL);

commit;
```

Notice the lower left and upper right coordinates are coincident. Technically this is a polygon per Oracle Spatial geometry rules but ArcGIS will not draw this, reconcile this, or even pull this up in an attribute table:

```
One or more layers failed to draw:

POLY_SDO:  The number of points is less than required for feature
```

The error is misleading since a quick vertex count will not show a problem.

Whereas this will produce a square:

```
INSERT INTO sde.poly_sdo VALUES(
  2,SDO_GEOMETRY(2003,4326,NULL,SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1,1, 2,2)),NULL);

commit;
```

I suggest to look into your geometry construction, especially if the data was loaded or created in SQL versus drawn in ArcMap.